# GHC type inference woes

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, typeclass, associated-types

*Question*. Is there any way to make this code work without an explicit type signature?

*Code*. First, I have a in-practice-much-nicer alternate `MonadTrans` class, inspired by `Data.Newtype`. It looks like this,

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

module Alt.Control.Monad.Trans where

import Control.Monad

class (Monad , Monad (BaseMonad )) => MonadTrans ( :: * -> *) where
    type BaseMonad  :: * -> *
    lift :: (BaseMonad ) α ->  α
```

Then, I have a class `A` with method `foo`, and if some base monad `M` is an `A`, then any transformed monad `T M` is also an `A`. In code,

```
class A  where
    foo :: String ->  ()

instance (A (BaseMonad ), MonadTrans ) => A  where
    foo n = lift $ foo n
```

However, if I now want to create a shortcut for `foo` with its first argument substituted, then I need an explicit type signature, or the compiler's context stack overflows.

```
minimize_call :: A  =>  ()
minimize_call = foo "minimize"
```

*Possible info to help inference*. Let's say we have an associated type `B :: * -> *`. I'm thinking that I want to tell the compiler `B` satisfies `B t /= t`, `B (B t) /= B t`, etc. i.e. `B` is somehow "monotonic" -- that chasing associated types is equivalent to removing newtype wrappers, and it should know that it cannot remove newtype wrappers forever, hence adding the context `A` to the signature is necessary.

Comment: sorry, should have bothered to remember _why_ I switched to the alternate `MonadTrans` ... for now, let's say it produces cleaner code, but I think there was a more substantial reason.

Comment: Interesting question. Why don't you want an explicit type signature though? Doesn't `minimize_call` have to be some fixed value, not a polymorphic constant (or maybe you can get it to be polymorphic, I'm not sure)? If it has some single fixed type, I would rather document that, and if it doesn't, I would rather document **that**. Forcing the reader to do whole program analysis in their head to figure out what type `minimize_call` has seems a bit counter-productive.

Comment: @Ben, It's true that, in this case, having a type signature for `minimize_call` is good practice. However, the type inference being broken suggests something is going wrong (with the design, compiler, or communication to the compiler), and will likely cause problems, not to mention unintelligible error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. Provide a grounded instance for `A`, and add `NoMonomorphismRestriction` to the language pragma (in addition to the also required `FlexibleInstances` and `UndecidableInstances`).

**However, the `A` class will be unusable.** There is no way for the compiler to know that there never will be a `MonadTrans` instance with `BaseMonad m = m`. Thus it cannot select an instance, ever, because it cannot know whether to use the instance from here or another one.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Trans (MonadTrans(..), A(..), minimize_call) where

import Control.Monad

class (Monad m, Monad (BaseMonad m)) => MonadTrans (m :: * -> *) where
    type BaseMonad m :: * -> *
    lift :: (BaseMonad m) α -> m α

class A m where
    foo :: String -> m ()


data Foo a = Bork

instance Monad Foo where
    return _ = Bork
    _ >>= _ = Bork

instance A Foo where
    foo _ = Bork


instance (A (BaseMonad m), MonadTrans m) => A m where
    foo n = lift $ foo n

-- minimize_call :: A m => m ()
minimize_call = foo "minimize"
```

compiles with ghc 6.12, 7.0, 7.2 and 7.4. Without the signature, `minimize_call` must get a monomorphic type, unless the MR is turned off. That can't work anyway because the constraint `A m` is not defaultable. So therefore the MR must be turned off. But then the type checker still chases its own tail trying to prove the constraint is satisfiable. With only the lifting instance, it can't. If you provide an anchor, it can.

But providing a type signature is much much better.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the grounded instance in the module. There, in fact, may be multiple grounded instances, depending on how many backends I have to my compiler, and assuming the use of one particular one is undesirable. I already have `FlexibleInstances`, `FlexibleContexts`, and `NoMonomorphismRestriction` turned on.

Comment: You can use a not-exported dummy monad, see update. The inferred type of `minimize_call` is `A m => m ()`, as it should be, it doesn't preclude using different grounded instances elsewhere, it's just necessary to let the type checker terminate.

Comment: Actually, no you can't use `minimize_call`, or `foo` at all. With or without type signature.

Comment: Hmm, will take a look at your "A will be unusable" assertion. I've been using this pattern successfully, but perhaps there were some subtle differences, or I haven't tried making it run though multiple base instances of `A`.